# Unable to open zig lib directory 'https:/github.com/chadwain/rem.git': FileNotFound

Tags: zig

I'm trying to use https://github.com/chadwain/rem, and want to add it to my `build.zig` file as below:

```rs
const std = @import("std");
pub fn build(b: *std.Build) void {
    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});
    const optimize = b.standardOptimizeOption(.{});

    const path = std.build.LazyPath{ .path = "https://github.com/chadwain/rem.git" };
    const exe = b.addExecutable(.{
        .name = "html-txt",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/main.zig" },
        .target = target,
        .optimize = optimize,
        .zig_lib_dir = path,
    });

    b.installArtifact(exe);

    const run_cmd = b.addRunArtifact(exe);

    run_cmd.step.dependOn(b.getInstallStep());

    // This allows the user to pass arguments to the application in the build
    // command itself, like this: `zig build run -- arg1 arg2 etc`
    if (b.args) |args| {
        run_cmd.addArgs(args);
    }

    const run_step = b.step("run", "Run the app");
    run_step.dependOn(&run_cmd.step);
}
```

But failed, and got the below error:

```
$ zig build
zig build-exe html-txt Debug native: error: error: unable to open zig lib directory 'https:/github.com/chadwain/rem.git': FileNotFound

zig build-exe html-txt Debug native: error: the following command exited with error code 1:
/usr/bin/zig build-exe /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/html-txt/src/main.zig --cache-dir /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/html-txt/zig-cache --global-cache-dir /home/hasany/.cache/zig --name html-txt --zig-lib-dir /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/html-txt/https:/github.com/chadwain/rem.git --listen=- 
Build Summary: 0/3 steps succeeded; 1 failed (disable with --summary none)
install transitive failure
└─ install html-txt transitive failure
   └─ zig build-exe html-txt Debug native failure
error: the following build command failed with exit code 1:
/home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/html-txt/zig-cache/o/6e0a152f1b25945f81d097452bce1b34/build /usr/bin/zig /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/html-txt /home/hasany/Documents/zig-tutorial/html-txt/zig-cache /home/hasany/.cache/zig
```

**NOTE**

I aware that I can download it as: `$ git clone https://github.com/chadwain/rem.git`

and write the `build.zig` as:

```rs
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});
    const optimize = .ReleaseFast;

    const exe = b.addExecutable(.{
        .name = "myexe1",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "src/main.zig" },
        .target = target,
        .optimize = optimize,
    });

    const rem_src = "rem/rem.zig";

    const rem_module = b.addModule("rem", .{
        .source_file = .{ .path = rem_src },
    });

    exe.addModule("rem", rem_module);

    const run_step = b.step("run", "Run the app");
    run_step.dependOn(&exe.step);
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to use the url path.

Comment: AFAIK `.path` needs to be a file path, not a URL. Also the repo you linked to says that it is only compatible with Zig v0.10.1; v0.10.1 had `std.build.FileSource` which has since been renamed to `std.Build.LazyPath`. What version of Zig are you trying to use?

Comment: @adabsurdum I'm trying versiin `0.11.0`